# What is the meta information in a *_DCPS.hpp file generated from an IDL (using cyclonedds-cxx)?

Tags: metadata, idl, data-distribution-service

I use cyclonedds-cxx and their IDL compiler to translate IDL files for the use with cyclonedds-cxx. I have this IDL file:

```
#ifndef TRANSPORTDATA_IDL
#define TRANSPORTDATA_IDL

#include "Transform_.idl"

module TransportData
{
  struct Data
  {
    long userID; //@key
    geometry_msgs::msg::dds_::Transform_ transform_;
  };
  #pragma keylist Data userID
};

#endif  // TRANSPORTDATA_IDL
```

This IDL file is, among others, converted to Transportdata_DCPS.hpp, which looks like this:

```cpp
#ifndef ISOCPP2_TRANSPORTDATA_H
#define ISOCPP2_TRANSPORTDATA_H

#include "dds/dds.hpp"

#include "TransportData.h"
#include "TransportDataSplDcps.h"

#include "org/eclipse/cyclonedds/topic/TopicTraits.hpp"
#include "org/eclipse/cyclonedds/topic/DataRepresentation.hpp"

namespace org { namespace eclipse { namespace cyclonedds { namespace topic {
template <>
class TopicTraits<TransportData::Data>
{
public:
    static ::org::eclipse::cyclonedds::topic::DataRepresentationId_t getDataRepresentationId()
    {
        return ::org::eclipse::cyclonedds::topic::OSPL_REPRESENTATION;
    }

    static ::std::vector<uint8_t> getMetaData()
    {
        return ::std::vector<uint8_t>();
    }

    static ::std::vector<uint8_t> getTypeHash()
    {
        return ::std::vector<uint8_t>();
    }

    static ::std::vector<uint8_t> getExtentions()
    {
        return ::std::vector<uint8_t>();
    }

    static const char *getKeyList()
    {
        return "userID";
    }

    static const char *getTypeName()
    {
        return "TransportData::Data";
    }

    static const dds_topic_descriptor_t *getDescriptor()
    {
        return &TransportData_Data_desc;
    }

    static copyInFunction getCopyIn()
    {
        return (copyInFunction) __TransportData_Data__copyIn;
    }

    static copyOutFunction getCopyOut()
    {
        return (copyOutFunction) __TransportData_Data__copyOut;
    }

    static size_t getSampleSize()
    {
        return sizeof(TransportData_Data);
    }
};
}}}}

namespace dds { namespace topic {
template <>
struct topic_type_name<TransportData::Data>
{
    static std::string value()
    {
        return org::eclipse::cyclonedds::topic::TopicTraits<TransportData::Data>::getTypeName();
    }
};
}}

REGISTER_TOPIC_TYPE(TransportData::Data)
#endif /* ISOCPP_TRANSPORTDATA_H */
```

I have three questions about this:

- Where can I find a documentation of the meta information?
- Is this meta information guaranteed to be there by the DDS standard?
- What are the `copyInFunction`and the `copyOutFunction` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all implementation-specific and with the new IDL compiler for Cyclone, the output will change completely, even eliminating most of the generated files.

The `copyInFunction` and `copyOutFunction` here refer to functions that copy samples from the C++ representation to an internal representation and back. For the initial commit of the C++ API, this internal representation is actually the sample in C representation, after which it gets converted to/from CDR. The new version does away with these functions and avoids this copy.